# X beats Y beats Z

Tags: verbs, writing-style

On one of my pages, I have the following text:

> If a tie occurs, the tie is broken as follows: Spicy beats Dry beats Sweet beats Bitter beats Sour, and Spicy beats Sour.

This text explains how ties are broken, for example, Spicy wins over Dry, and Dry wins over Sweet.

Is it good style or usage to chain each item with "beats" this way?  It's not mentioned in Garner's Modern
American Usage or in Pocket Fowler's, as far as I can tell.  Does the chaining of "beats" make
the text confusing or otherwise not ideal?

---

I'm also interested in learning the origin of this form, "X beats Y beats Z", which is a so-called "anti-grammatical" form.  When did it start?  Why did writers use this form rather than "X beats Y, which beats Z"?  Is this form mentioned in any reference works?

---

Here are some examples I've just found:

- http://www.dragonflycave.com/faq.aspx
- http://www.starcitygames.com/magic/misc/11387_SCG_Daily_The_Process_of_Choosing_Your_Deck.html
- http://www.comicvine.com/myvine/joey_ravn/forums/?page=2
- http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/4926492991
- http://www.rpgdl.com/archives/509

Comment: Sounds fine to me, and I can't think of any clearer way to write it. Grammatical purists might object.

Comment: Belongs on writers.st -- voting to close as off-topic on EL&U.

Comment: Would the same structure in another language present a different set of problems?

Comment: @Kris:  Writers?  As of now I was only familiar with English Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, and so on.  The network seems to be growing so fast.

Comment: @PeterO., check [this](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) out!  However, four or five are [closing today](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/).

Comment: I think you only need to scroll down to the page-footer that lists the SE sites with hyperlinks. (not on mobile version)

Comment: "Spicy beats Dry beats Sweet beats Bitter beats Sour" is clear enough, but you then say "Spicy beats Sour".  Because one would automatically deduce the latter by transitivity, saying it separately is confusing.

Comment: -1 Please show research results. Are there other examples of this construction or is it entirely your invention?

Comment: @ΜετάEd: I've added examples according to your request.

Comment: @JamesWaldby-jwpat7 Not necessarily: Rock beats scissors beats paper, but paper beats rock. Adding "spicy beats sour" makes it clear the relationship is transitive rather than cyclic.

Comment: @NoName, adding "spicy beats sour" makes it easier to *assume* the relationship is transitive, but does little to *make it clear* it is so.  For example: denote the characteristics as a,b,c,d,e.  We are given a>b>c>d>e and a>e.  But perhaps b<d and c<e.  For clarity, one could replace "and Spicy beats Sour" (in the original) with "transitively".  :)

Answer (score 2):

> This text explains how ties are broken, for example, Spicy wins over
>   Dry, and Dry wins over Sweet.

What you have started here is a clearer way to say it, at least to my ear.  For example:

> Spicy beats dry, dry beats sweet, sweet beats bitter, bitter beats sour, and spicy beats sour (or bitter and spicy beat sour).

Comment: I also wanted to convey, for example, that Spicy beats Bitter, or Dry beats Sour.  Would it work to say, somehow, that the five things are ranked?

Comment: Certainly.  I would advise you to use any and all descriptions necessary in the interest of communicating clear rules.

Comment: I've decided to use the following: "If a tie occurs, then the flavors are ranked as follows to break the tie: Spicy first, then Dry, then Sweet, then Bitter, then Sour."

Comment: This discussion reminds me of [this picture](http://picchore.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/rock-paper-scissors-why-does-paper-beat-rock.jpg)